# Show how long does it take for the script to be completed

Tags: python

I wrote a python code like this

```
total = 500
a = 0
for i in range(500):
    a += 1
```

And I want to show something like [the photo i uploaded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DQgLO.png) in terminal

Is there a module that can do this for me?
or How can I do this?

Comment: From the *time* module you could use the *perf_counter()* function. Also consider the *timeit* module

Answer (score 3):

Use time module

```
import time
start_time = time.time()
main()
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: time.perf_counter() is generally preferred

Answer (score 1):

I do not know much about any libraries that support **progress bar**s like one in your attached photo.

However, for **timing your code**, the best two options from the Python Standard Library are from the `time` and `timeit` module.

From the `time` module ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html)), you should use `time.perf_counter()` (unit of time = seconds) or `time.perf_counter_ns()` (unit of time = nanoseconds, helps combat precision loss due to `float` in `perf_counter`). These are recommended/preferred over `time.time()` for the purposes of timing code.

Example usage:

```
import time

def foo(x):
    return x * x 
    
if __name__ == '__main__':

    # not meaningful on it's own
    start_time = time.perf_counter_ns()
    # a very silly example, but for illustration
    foo(5)
    # not meaningful on it's own
    end_time = time.perf_counter_ns()
    # taking difference meaningful
    print(f"Time elapsed: {end_time - start_time} nanoseconds")
```

Output

```
Time elapsed: 581 nanoseconds
```

The `timeit` module ([documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html)) is well-suited for timing small chunks of Python code. Using the code you provided, here is an example:

```
import timeit

def foo():
    total = 500
    a = 0
    for i in range(500):
        a += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(timeit.timeit("foo()", setup="from __main__ import foo", number=100000))
```

Output

```
1.2454171699937433
```

indicating it took about 1.245 seconds to execute `foo()` 100,000 = `number` times. `number` can be changed to whatever you want.

Hope this helps!